# Iframe child to parent communication with multiple iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to implement some iframe communications. I have the fallowing page hosted on http://parent.com :

```
<html>
   <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://child.com"/>
   <iframe id="iframe2" src="http://child.com"/>
   <iframe id="iframe3" src="http://child.com"/>
</html>
```

I m trying to use postMessage to make communication between iframe1 and iframe2 possible but i can't seem to find how.

Here is so code i have in the child iframe :

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent, function(event) {
   event.source.postMessage("somerandomdata", "http://child.com)
}, false);
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [cross-document messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

**Parent window:**

```
 myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
```

**Child iframe:**

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
    if (e.data == 'hello') {
        alert('It works!');
    }
};
```

Comment: Also be sure to checkout this for i-frame comms: http://pbojinov.github.io/iframe-communication/

Comment: I already use this method for parent to child communication as in my exemple. What i can't figure out is how to communicate from child to child. Without the parent having to act as an intermediary

Answer (score 2):

You can send messages to parent by,

```
// Send a message to the parent
var sendMessage = function (msg) {
    // Make sure you are sending a string, and stringified JSON
    window.parent.postMessage(msg, '*');
};
```

you can find a very useful sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299)

Answer (score 1):

Finally figure it out. You need to have a name on all iframe :

```
<html>
   <iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="http://child.com"/>
   <iframe id="iframe2" name="iframe2" src="http://child.com"/>
   <iframe id="iframe3" name="iframe3"src="http://child.com"/>
</html>
```

Then from a child frame you can do this :

```
window.parent.frames["iframe1"]
```